# How do I make an image relative to the screen size in css?

Tags: html, css, sizing

I have an image background in css and 2 images overlaying that. On my device I can line them up perfectly the way I want, but when I go to view them on another device or change my screen size, the 2 overlaying images change size and position while the background doesn't. I know there's a line of css that I'm missing or doing wrong, so if anyone could help it would be much appreciated. Thanks, and here's my code:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Next time also add the related HTML; it makes it easier for us to amend it. Use the <code> in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind actually, I just found out that by using percents instead of pixels for the positions and width it automatically adjusts.

Comment: also use relative positioning, and use percentage for placing it, e.g. margin-left:10%; as well as using percentage for width (and auto for height)